# VBA adding secondary axis error "object doesnt support this property or method"

Tags: excel, vba, charts

So I am trying to add a secondary axis to the `XYScatter` plot but I keep getting an error stating object doesn't support property or method

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Sheet2'!$A$9"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Sheet2'!$B$9"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Sheet2'!$C$9"

With Sheets(3).ChartObjects("Chart 8")
  .SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = xlSecondary ' (Error Occurs here)
  .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlPrimary) = True
  .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlSecondary) = True
  .HasAxis(xlValue, xlPrimary) = True
  .HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
End With

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Sheet2'!$D$9"
```

Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another `SeriesCollection` using `Sheets(3).ChartObjects("Chart 8")     .SeriesCollection.Add` before using it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, please elaborate

Comment: Error here, correct? .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic

Comment: Sorry,  the error occurs on 

.SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = xlSecondary     (Error Occurs here)

Answer (score -4):

For 3-D charts, only xlPrimary is valid.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartgroup.axisgroup

Comment: the code of the OP clearly states `ChartType = xlXYScatter`

Comment: Even if it did not, the error would be about an invalid value supplied to the property, not about the property itself missing.